# Identifying when scp is stalling using python

Tags: python, linux, scp

Other Q&As on Stack Overflow have already addressed how to launch SCP using Python and its standard library. How do I determine the scp transfer is stalling using python so that I can react to it?

**Context**
I have access to Python 2.6 and its standard library. I am unable to use additional packages in my working environment. Rsync is also unavailable and we're forced to use scp (no ftp either).

I'm trying to write a script that identifies a stalled transfer, ends it and restarts using a different node.

Thanks

Comment: The way I determine if `scp` has stalled is by how long the process is hanging.  How are you determining if the connection has stalled if not this?  If it is just a time out thing why not check how long the process is running and kill it if it goes over.  Or better yet set the time out parameter for `scp` directly.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not concerned about the scp process stalling but the data transfer itself. Typically it displays "--stalling--" in the standard output.

Using a time based window to complete a transfer requires prior knowledge of the file sizes and an assumed transfer speed etc, which makes it inefficient.